# Can not connect from ACI to Azure SQL Server

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, azure-container-instances

I have a C# application in .Net 8 that uses the Entity framework to connect to the SQL database. I am using the SQL Authentication in the connection string. In my local I run the container I can connect to the Azure SQL Server and everything is good but when I run the container inside the Azure Container Instance with the exact same image and environment variable I get this error when i want to connect to the exact same database that I connect in my local . I white listed my Azure Container Instance public Id and my local. also I checked the "Allow Azure Services and Instances to this Server".

In the Azure SQL Server networking I set :Public network access with selected networks and just in case in the firewall rules I added "0.0.0.0" to "255.255.255.255"

```
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
  Connection id "0HN1SVGHL7U9F", Request id "0HN1SVGHL7U9F:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
   ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer"
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `TrustServerCertificate=True` in your connection string ?

Comment: yes and it did not work